# use the measuring unit of cols in css

Tags: html, css

I have a `<textarea>` object, `50 cols width`. I want a `<button>` as wide as the `<textarea>` object. is this possible?. and if not, how many pixels are one `cols`. or I'm confused and the `cols` don't determent the  `width` of the `<textarea>` at all. in this case, what is the default `width` of an `<textarea>` object?

(i prefer not to use  javascript to get the width as I'm building a chrome extension so its have to be lightweight)

thank you in advance!

edit:

if I have to use `width` for that, ok. but I want the exact same width as have right now as it is fit perfectly. so how can I convert the cols to width? I use the latest CSS edition (as well as last HTML), and the page runs only on chrome.

Comment: `cols` is dependent on the OS, browser, installed fonts,  etc. Specify a width instead via CSS.

Comment: Do you have to use `cols` for the `textarea`? You could just give it width in CSS

Comment: Since your edit: to get the width in pixels, just open up dev tools in chrome and inspect the `textarea` element. It will give you the height and width of the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you've composed your HTML — please remember to show your [mcve] code in your questions, it makes it far easier for us to help and offer practical advice — there are some options:

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  /* forcing all elements, and the listed pseudo-elements,
     to use the border-box sizing; including padding and
     margins into the calculated width: */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* resetting margin and padding to zero for consistency: */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

div {
  /* the default margin for all <div> elements, to move them
     apart from the left-edge of the viewport and away from
     their predecessor: */
  margin: 1em 0 0 1em;
}

div.withBlock {
  /* we want the <div> to collapse to the size of the
     <textarea>: */
  display: inline-block;
}

div.withBlock textarea {
  /* using display: block to force the <button> to a new
     line: */
  display: block;
}

div.withBlock button {
  /* specifying a 100% width, which will cause the
     <button> to be the full width of the parent -
     <div> - element, which is itself shrunk down 
     to the width of the <textarea>: */
  width: 100%;
  /* to separate the two elements for visibility: */
  margin-top: 10px;
}

div.withGrid {
  /* using CSS Grid layout: */
  display: grid;
  /* defining the one column as min-content, which
     causes the column to be the minimum width 
     required to display its largest content (in this
     case that is the <textarea> with its defined width:*/
  grid-template-columns: min-content;
  /* to separate the contents from each other with a
     10px gutter: */
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

div.withFlex {
  /* this emulates the previous 'display: inline,' but
     uses the flexbox layout within the <div>; causing
     the <div> to collapse to the size of its largest
     child element: */
  display: inline-flex;
  /* the automatic value of flex-direction is 'row,' so
     because we want columns (I think) we're specifying
     the following value: */
  flex-direction: column;
}

div.withFlex button {
  margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```html
<!-- we wrap each <textarea> and <button> pair in a parent <div>,
     though in practice you may have them wrapped in something
     like a <fieldset>, or the <textarea> may be wrapped in a
     <label> with the <button> being a sibling of that <label> -->
<div class="withBlock">
  <textarea cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
  <button>the button</button>
</div>

<div class="withGrid">
  <textarea cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
  <button>the button</button>
</div>

<div class="withFlex">
  <textarea cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
  <button>the button</button>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/3nzw1hau/2/).

Comment: and it actually changes the size of the button when textarea is resized!

Answer (score 2):

to have width being equally calcuated from an element to another, no matter how different the padding or border-width elements can be , you may reset `box-sizing` :

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing
>
> The `box-sizing` CSS property sets how the total width and height of an element is calculated.

```css
textarea,
button {
  box-sizing: border-box;/* includes border and padding into size calculation */
  width: 200px;
}
/* demo purpose to show where both textarea/button stand and take width */
div {
  display:table;
  border:solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <textarea></textarea><br/>
    <button>Click</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The default width of a textarea is 20 `cols`. One `col` is equal to the average character width so you will be able to fit an average of 50 characters per line if you have a width of 50 `cols`. You can set the width of both the `<textarea>` and `<button>` using CSS to ensure they end up the same width.

In Chrome Version 75.0.3770.142 `<textarea cols='50'>`  has a clientWidth of 381

Comment: so what width is that?

Answer (score 1):

People already have answered that instead of `col` use CSS to specify the width of both `textarea` and `button`. However, even if you give the same pixel width for both, still the button will be little smaller than the `textarea`. In case you are using pixel for specifying width give `7px` more for the button. Notice that button has default padding: `1px 7px 2px`.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="width:100%">
    <textarea style="width:200px"></textarea><br/>
    <button style="width:207px">Click</button>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so you say i should give the button 7 more px then it "should?"

Comment: @avivgood3 run the snippet from the answer. Try this yourself with different pixel width of the `button` and `textarea` 100px, 50px, 300px, etc. and you'll see 7px more in the button will make them equal width.